# Sorting a 1d array of Objects from a file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

Good Afternoon, I have a final project to do and need some help. I would just like to grasp the algorithm of sorting a 1d array of objects from a file. I know how to do it with a regular array using a counter in a for loop or a for each loop. I'm having difficulty reproducing it with with my objects. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void printFile()throws IOException {
    File f = new File("program7b.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(f);

    int count = 0;
    Customer[] obj = new Customer[in.nextInt()];
    while(in.hasNext() ){
        int id = in.nextInt();
        String name = in.next();
        String email = in.next();
        double balance = in.nextDouble();
        in.nextLine();


        obj[count] = new Customer (id, name, email, balance);
        count++;

    }

    in.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        System.out.println(obj[i]);

        if (obj[i] instanceof TaxExempt){
            System.out.println("Tax Type: " + ((TaxExempt)obj[i]).getExempt());
        }

    }
}

public static void sortCust(Customer[] id){
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < id.length-1; i++){

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, could you add what you've done so far ?

Comment: Could you also restrict your code to the relevent part ? In doubt, please refer the the [how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, you would use a compareTo method in the class of the object. Since objects can have multiple instance variables and other objects within them, you have to pick a specific field to sort on.

Say you have an object (Account) with a person's name and bank balance. You would want to sort by bank balance.

```
public int compareTo(Account a){
if(balance<a.getBalance())
     return -1; 
if(balance==a.getBalance())
     return 0; 
else
     return 1; 

}
```

Now that you have a compare to, you can bubble sort/quick sort/selection sort (I barely even know what those mean anymore), just like you would with an array of ints.

The biggest difference is that your condition will specify object.compareTo(otherObject) and will be based on if it is <0, ==0, or >0.

Be careful when you are moving objects though. You want to make sure to do a deep copy of all the details in the objects, not just copy the objects. For this reason, I recommend a swap method and a copy method.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, @Tyler H